# Inductive function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to understand what is meant by an inductive set.  I've found it to be defined as: if z is in a set K then $$z\cup \{z\} $$ is in the set.  How is this possible since the reunion is between sets in general?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definition is incomplete. We say that $I$ is inductive set when $\emptyset\in I$ and $(\forall z\in I)\ z\cup\{z\}\in I$.

Inductive sets appear, for example, in ZFC, where Axiom of infinity postulates existence of inductive set, and consequently the existence of *the set of natural numbers*. What seems to be your misunderstanding is that you are not treating $z$ as a set, but in ZFC everything is a set. Thus, $z\cup\{z\}$ is a set that contains all elements of $z$ and $z$ itself.

Let $z = \emptyset\in I$. Then $z\cup\{z\} = \{\emptyset\}\in I$, and by iterating the process, $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\in I$, $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ etc. We usually denote these sets by $0$, $1$, $2$, $3\ldots$, respectively.

Comment: respectively...?

Comment: @Andrés, yes, thank you. Funny typo, though :)

Comment: "Please sir $\varnothing$, allow me to call you $0$"

Answer (score 0):

You may be used to sets of numbers but with set theory you have to think of sets containing sets that contain sets ...  The notation $z\cup\{z\}$ looks a bit odd at first. This creates a new set from z containing all the elements of $z$ and the set z as a member of the new set. If z = $\{a,b\}$ then $z\cup\{z\}$ = $\{a,b,\{a,b\}\}$

With induction we define a set $I$ by starting with one or more base elements in the first step, often $∅$, and then provide a rule for building ever larger supersets from prior elements. These new supersets will also be members of the inductive set $I$.